# Multiple Gridviews

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-gridview

I need to make an App that displays multiple gridviews but when one of the gridviews doesn't fit on the screen, It get scrollable, but just the gridview. I want to make the whole page scrollable. Here is the code:

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Mañana"
                android:textSize="20dp" />




            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/GridMorningClasses"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/padding_medium"
                tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" >

            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >




        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Tarde"
                android:textSize="20dp" />




            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/GridAfternoonClasses"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
                android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/padding_medium"
                tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" >

            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextView03"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
                android:text="Noche"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/GridNightClasses"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:horizontalSpacing="@dimen/padding_small"
                android:numColumns="5"
                android:verticalSpacing="@dimen/padding_medium"
                tools:listitem="@android:layout/simple_list_item_2" >
            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put everything inside a android.widget.ScrollView it should make the whole screen scroll at once.

Comment: I tried it but It makes all my gridviews scrollable, and I don't want that. I want my gridviews without scroll.